# Update query is not working, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

This update query is working but it does not update any field on table. Database is MSSQL.

This is the method on my page:

```
otAppMainSettingsBLL.updateGameDayWithTeamID(1, true);
```

This is Business Logic Layer:

```
public bool updateGameDayWithTeamID(int teamID, bool myValue)
    {
        return otAppMainSettingsDAL.updateGameDayWithTeamID(teamID, myValue);
    }
```

This is Data Access Layer:

```
 public bool updateGameDayWithTeamID(int teamID, bool myValue)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new KsEntities())
            {
                context.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE tAppMainSettings set isGameDay ='" + myValue + "' WHERE teamID = {0}", teamID);
            }
            dc.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

if i add this int value, like below: (int resultValue=0;)

```
public bool updateGameDayWithTeamID(int teamID, bool myValue)
    {
        int resultValue = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var context = new KsEntities())
            {
                resultValue = context.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE tAppMainSettings set isGameDay ='" + myValue + "' WHERE teamID = {0}", teamID);
            }
            dc.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am getting resultValue=1

Table name is:tAppMainSettings
Field is:isGameDay (cant be null, i mean, Allow Nulls checkbox is not checked and default value for this field is: ((0))          )

Comment: Why are you passing `myValue` by concatenating strings when you already use parameters for `teamId` ? Just write `isGameDay ={0} WHERE teamID = {1}",myValue, teamID)`

Comment: Do you have any existing transactions? It's *very* strange to use two contexts in the same method - you shouldn't need to call `dc.SaveChanges()` if you only want to execute a command in `context`. Are you using TransactionScope perhaps?

Comment: Looks like that `isGameDay` is a bit value, and you are setting it with a string: `' + myValue + '`. Am I right?

Comment: @FabioLuz I think I already commented on this but the comment "disappeared" - `catch{}` will hide any errors. If there is any problem with the query, like trying to put the word `False` in a bit column, the resulting error will be lost. The OP should at least debug the code and put a break point in the catch block. Logging the error is even better

Comment: Dear Fabio. Yes, isGameDay is a bit value. how can i set instead of '+myValue+'. I dont know how can i set (write) bool value? isGameDay=myValue. Like this?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos. let me try this. thanks

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos. i tried this. it works. thanks you too fabioLuz.

Comment: so my problem is solved. How can i mark my question "solved". I cant find this stackover flow "green check mark button".